# How to fit multiple exponential curves using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-analysis

For a single exponential curve such as shown in the image here [curve_fit for as single exponential curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aiqZz.png) , I am able to fit the data using scipy.optimize.curve_fit. However, I am unsure on how to realize a fit for similar dataset composed of multiple exponential curves as shown here [double exponential curves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H46N3.png).
I achieved the fit for the single curve using the following approach:

```
def exp_decay(x,a,r):
    return a * ((1-r)**x) 

x = np.linspace(0,50,50)
y = exp_decay(x, 400, 0.06)

y1 = exp_decay(x, 550, 0.06)      # this is to be used to append to y to generate two curves

pars, cov = curve_fit(exp_decay, x, y, p0=[0,0])
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(x, exp_decay(x, *pars), 'r-')     #this realizes the fit for a single curve

yx = np.append(y,y1)   #this realizes two exponential curves (as shown above - double exponential curves) for which I don't need to fit a model to
```

Can someone help describe how to achieve this for a dataset of two curves. My actual dataset comprises of multiple exponential curves but I think if I can realize a fit for two curves, I may be able to replicate same for my dataset. This must not be done with scipy's curve_fit; any implementation that works is fine.

PLEASE HELP !!!

Comment: good news/bad news.  If you can fit one curve to similar data (appears you can), then you can fit N curves.  You will obviously (?) need to fit them each individually by separating the data.  So...  potential bad news.  How are the data from the separate curves marked or distinguishable within your dataset?

Comment: @AirSquid Yea, I can for a single curve; but because it's a continuous dataset from some observation, separating the data isn't an option. The curves are repeating patterns for which I need to find a fit. These curves are of varying data points - varying periods. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Split dataset using first derivative criterion (the first difference is highly positive when curve change) then apply single curve fit either by shifting to origin or adding an extra lag parameter. Finally assemble results.

Comment: Well, you will clearly have to separate the data for different curves somehow.  How would the curve fitting algorithm know which curve to fit it to?  Suggest you augment your post with the data or maybe make a new post.  if the data is spaced out on your x-axis as in your example, there is some hope in either looking for big jumps or looking at derivative as suggested above...all depends on many things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem can easily be tackled by splitting your dataset using a simple criterion such as first derivative estimate and then we can apply simple curve fitting procedure to each sub dataset.

### Trial Dataset

First, let's import some packages and create a synthetic dataset with three curves to represent your problem.

We use a two parameters exponential model as time origin shift will be handled by the splitting methodology. We also add noise as there is always noise on real world data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def func(x, a, b):
    return a*np.exp(b*x)

N = 1001
n1 = N//3
n2 = 2*n1

t = np.linspace(0, 10, N)

x0 = func(t[:n1], 1, -0.2)
x1 = func(t[n1:n2]-t[n1], 5, -0.4)
x2 = func(t[n2:]-t[n2], 2, -1.2)

x = np.hstack([x0, x1, x2])
xr = x + 0.025*np.random.randn(x.size)
```

Graphically it renders as follow:

[image]

### Dataset Splitting

We can split the dataset into three sub-datasets using a simple criterion as first derivative estimate using first difference to assess it. The goal is to detect when curve drastically goes up or down (where dataset should be split. First derivative is estimated as follow):

```
dxrdt = np.abs(np.diff(xr)/np.diff(t))
```

The criterion requires an extra parameter (threshold) that must be tuned accordingly to your signal specifications. The criterion is equivalent to:

```
xcrit = 20
q = np.where(dxrdt > xcrit) # (array([332, 665], dtype=int64),)
```

And split index are:

```
idx = [0] + list(q[0]+1) + [t.size] # [0, 333, 666, 1001]
```

Mainly the criterion threshold will be affected by the nature and the power of the noise on your data and the gap magnitudes between two curves. The usage of this methodology depends on the ability to detect curves gap in presence of noise. It will break when the noise power has the same magnitude of the gap we want to detect. You can also observe false split index if the noise is heavily tailed (few strong outliers).

In this MCVE, we have set the threshold to `20 [Signal Units/Time Units]`:

[image]

An alternative to this hand-crafted criterion is to delegate the identification to the excellent [`find_peaks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.find_peaks.html) method of `scipy`. But it will not avoid the requirement to tune the detection to your signal specifications.

### Fit origin-shifted dataset

Now we can apply the curve fitting on each sub-dataset (with origin shifted time), collect parameters and statistics and plot the result:

```
trials = []
fig, axe = plt.subplots()
for k, (i, j) in enumerate(zip(idx[:-1], idx[1:])):
    p, s = optimize.curve_fit(func, t[i:j]-t[i], xr[i:j])
    axe.plot(t[i:j], xr[i:j], '.', label="Data #{}".format(k+1))
    axe.plot(t[i:j], func(t[i:j]-t[i], *p), label="Data Fit #{}".format(k+1))
    trials.append({"n0": i, "n1": j, "t0": t[i], "a": p[0], "b": p[1],
                   "s_a": s[0,0], "s_b": s[1,1], "s_ab": s[0,1]})
axe.set_title("Curve Fits")
axe.set_xlabel("Time, $t$")
axe.set_ylabel("Signal Estimate, $\hat{g}(t)$")
axe.legend()
axe.grid()
df = pd.DataFrame(trials)
```

It returns the following fitting results:

```
    n0    n1    t0         a         b       s_a           s_b      s_ab
0    0   333  0.00  0.998032 -0.199102  0.000011  4.199937e-06 -0.000005
1  333   666  3.33  5.001710 -0.399537  0.000013  3.072542e-07 -0.000002
2  666  1001  6.66  2.002495 -1.203943  0.000030  2.256274e-05 -0.000018
```

Which complies with our original parameters (see Trial dataset section).

Graphically we can check the goodness of fits:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. This really seems to be it. Would it be possible to get the entire jupyter notebook file for your implementation with all the plots? Just to get a better feel of the technique (never done this before). Thanks once more.

Comment: @Ziggey, You are welcome. If you feel it is appropriate you can mark it as answer. Here is the notebook: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jlandercy/cookbook/master/python/stackoverflow/ExpFit.ipynb

Comment: I suppose having a background idea of the threshold is very important here. If this knowledge isn't handy, how could this be achieved? "The criterion requires an extra parameter (threshold) that must be tuned accordingly to your signal specifications." Can you describe how this may be achieved without this information handy?

Comment: How did you come up with 20 as threshold?

Comment: I ran 5 draws and I chose it visually for this MCVE. If your noise can be assumed as normal you may set this threshold about 5 sigma (scale it properly to have correct units). That will be a good start. You can estimate it from past data and assess how well it performs with freshly acquired data. As long as your process remains stable it should work. But this off course depends on your process and hypothesis we can draw from it.

Comment: Many thanks. This indeed provides some valuable direction and does perfectly address the problem. Will close off as an answer. I will try getting my threshold right. Thanks for taking out time to deal with this. One more last thing, could you please suggest a good literature on first derivative estimation like this. Cheers. You could link it up somewhere here or maybe on the jupyter notebook on Github.

Comment: I am glad it addressed your issue. Well, this knowledge brings me back 15 years ago when I did a lot of chromatography (where peak identification is crucial) and I had to daily post-process raw signals. I am afraid I have no reference left as this. Anyway if the method is very crude and not that subtle in the other hand it is intuitive and very easy to explain. If I'll find some reference later on I let you know. Cheers.

Comment: My apologies for being Oliver Twist here. I was just curious on how this could be achieved with scipy.signal.find_peaks because I implemented it (using the find_peaks on the auto-correlated signal to detect the period) and my indices[23, 39, 62, 85] were different from those obtained using the approach above [0, 23, 62, 108].

Comment: @Ziggey, that seems to be another question. Anyway it will be difficult to address it without having more information (see  [mcve]), please consider create a new question about how to tune `signal_peak`, create a MCVE (with real input, why you think auto-correlation is a problem, what is the expected output). You may send me a @ in comment to warn me when it is done. I would do my best to answer. Cheers